# How can I resolve conflicts between System.threading.Tasks and Net35.Threading.Tasks?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, dotnet-httpclient

I am working on an old .net application which has net35 version. I've need to use `System.Net.Http` but I can't use `System.Net.Http` as it was introduced after net35. To resolve this, I've installed [RackSpace.Httpclient35](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rackspace.HttpClient35/1.0.0-beta003). Now I can create HttpClient and use functionalities.

However, installing this have created conflict with `System.Threading.Tasks` library. Wherever I am using `Task<string>`, I get error saying

> Error CS0433  The type 'Task' exists in both 'Net35.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b3b1c0202c0d6a87' and 'System.Threading.Tasks.NET35, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

I've tried to force full path to library as `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>` still same error.

I've changed csproj file to explicitly add `System.Threading.Tasks` library.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net35</TargetFramework>
    <NullableContextOptions>enable</NullableContextOptions>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <WarningLevel>9999</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <WarningLevel>9999</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Net4x.Serilog" Version="2.12.1-at20230411063734" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Rackspace.HttpClient35" Version="1.0.0-beta003">
          <ExcludeAssets>runtime; contentfiles; analyzers; build</ExcludeAssets>
          <IncludeAssets>compile; native</IncludeAssets>
      </PackageReference>
      <PackageReference Include="System.Threading.Tasks" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Threading">
          <HintPath>path\net35\System.Threading.Tasks.NET35.dll</HintPath>
          <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I have also tried to bindingRedirect in `app.config`, still same error.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Net35.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b3b1c0202c0d6a87" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

How can I force my code to use `System.Threading.Tasks`? Unfortunately, I don't have option to upgrade .net version as we already have a new version product, this one is legacy one which needs more maintenance.

Comment: https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/dotnet-httpclient35/issues/10 Looks to me you have to fix that yourself in the source instead of using the nuget package. Does not look to complicated as the threading part is itself a dependency to a nuget package hosting the Threading stuff that hopefully just needs to be replaced by a dependency on "System.Threading.Tasks".

Comment: @Ralf Thank you for taking time to look into this. I tried to fix source files I got from git, it gives too many errors in the code files. there are some additional functions that are implemented in RackSpace Threading library that is not available in standard system.threading. Is there anyway I can force my code to ignore problematic lib?